# Deployment to Azure from Git, and git in general

Tags: git, azure

The way i have been working with Git for my private use is to have one private repository at Github.

I have multiply projects located in this repository:

/root/project1
/root/project2

I normally then have two branches that i switch between depending on what project i work on.

(mostly visual studio projects).

I now would like to push my project to Azure Websites and are not 100% sure what/how i want to do this.

I tried to find a way to just push project2, by going to command line and adding another remote azure from the project2 folder. It didnt work, it seemed like it moved both project 1 and 2 and then failed the deployment as it didnt know which project to compile.

Alternative, i could create a new local git and from visual studio publish to this remote and then push that to Azure. Any comments if thats what i want to do, seems little extra ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments, which explains how you can create a .deployment file to choose what project to deploy.

You can also set up Azure to deploy a specific branch from your repo (it's in the Configure tab).

Comment: Things worked out nicely, its really easy to deploy things now with git on websites. Looking forward to that coming to web services too ;)